# User's friend list tableview is empty and parse query did not return any data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

This is my code in swift

```
class UserViewController: UITableViewController {

var userArray: NSMutableArray = []

@IBOutlet weak var friendListTableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       retrieveMessages()

   }
func retrieveMessages() {
    var query = PFUser.query()
    if let username = PFUser.currentUser().username {
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in

        for object in objects! {
            let usernames:String? = (object as PFObject)["Friends"] as? String
            println(usernames) // It prints nil
            if usernames != nil {
                self.userArray.addObject(usernames!)
            }
        }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.friendListTableView.reloadData()
                }

    }

}
}
            override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return userArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Update - replace as with as!

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = userArray[indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell
}
```

I've saved current user's friend list with PFRelation in class "User" in column "Friends", here's how I save it

```
class addUserViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func addUser(sender: AnyObject) {
    var query = PFUser.query()
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameTextField.text)
    println("Pass")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{ (object:PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
            let friendList = currentUser.relationForKey("Friends")

            var addFriend = object
            if addFriend != nil {
                friendList.addObject(addFriend)
                println("added")
            }
            PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) in

                if error != nil {
                    println("Error")
                }
                else {
                    println("saved")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and now I want to retrieve current user's friend list to show it in tableview but The problem is I can't update tableview to show current user's friend list, It's empty and there's no user list in tableview at all. Is my code correct for this method? If not please help me correct this code

here's the screenshot of my User's class table in parse
[image: Parse user list]

here's the screenshot of my current user's friend in parse which is save with PFRelation 
[image: Parse friend user list]
Any help is appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: It didn't work. Perhaps this is about my method of retrieve current user's object?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Parse in a while, but if I'm not mistaken, the first query (in the first chunk of code) isn't built correctly. Should be like this:

```
 var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
 if let username = PFUser.currentUser().username {
   query.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)
   query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {....}
 }
```

The difference here is that you query the current user's username and not the object itself. Does this help?

Comment: Will try that in a sec. I'll let you know if this work. thank you!

Comment: and you should not query using the username. That's why you have object ids.

Comment: I try your method and It didn't work. probably another section of the code? (I've update my latest code in the question)

Comment: I think there's also an issue here: let username:String? = (object as PFObject)["Friends"] as? String. I'm guessing that object["Friends"] returns an array and not a string as you try to retrieve

Comment: So what should I change it into? Thanks

Comment: I've tried to change it to an array but I don't know how. Can you guide me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the array to NSMutableArray , and check if it appends the data.

```
var userArray: NSMutableArray = []
```

In retrieveMessages when trying to query the Parse "User" table use

```
var query = PFUser.query()
```

and then you are not passing the username as String
try

```
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
```

Comment: I try it and it didn't work. Probably some error in another section? please help. Thank you

Comment: you already have         self.friendListTableView.reloadData()      , so try NSMutableArray

Comment: instead of init the userArray as you did copy paste my code.  var userArray: NSMutableArray = []

Comment: I do that and the table's still empty. I try println(username) and it prints nil, mean that it didn't get the object at all. How do I fix this? Thanks